# getUrl() not working

Tags: matrix, url, image-transforms

I have the following code in the “main.twig” template:

```
<head>
    {% block head %}
        <meta property="og:image" content="{% block pageImage %}{% endblock %}" />
    {% endblock %}
</head>
```

Then, I’m trying to populate the image URL into the < meta > tag from a Matrix field:

```
{% extends "templates/main" %}
{% for block in entry.articleBody %}
    {% if block.type == "articleImage" %}
        {% set image = block.articleImage.first().getUrl() %}
        {% block pageImage %}{{ image }}{% endblock %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% block head %}{{ parent() }}{% endblock %}
```

However, no URL is outputted. Does anyone know why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Twig generally doesn't like nested/un-nested blocks like this. A better way to deal with this would be to just set a variable; and since twig renders templates from the inside-out, any variables that you define in child-templates should be available to the parent.

So in 'main.twig':

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:image" content="{% if seoImage is defined %}{{ seoImage }}{% endif %}" />
</head>
```

And in your child-template:

```
{% extends "templates/main" %}

{# note: needs to be defined outside the 'for' loop to become available #}
{% set seoImage="" %} 
{% for block in entry.articleBody %}
    {% if block.type == "articleImage" %}
        {% set seoImage = block.articleImage.first().getUrl() %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can still use blocks of course in addition to this technique, but generally best to keep them in the same nesting order.

On a side-note: I don't think you need the 'templates/' part of the extends statement (unless you have a 'templates' folder inside 'templates'). Normally you would just use `{% extends "_main" %}`. The underscore in the name also prevents the template from being loaded directly.

Comment: Also, yes, I do have a ‘templates’ folder inside ‘craft/templates’—a bit confusing, but helps me distinguish templates called by Routing from child templates, which I put into a separate ‘includes’ folder.

Comment: That did it! Thank you, Douglas! I also didn’t know I had to define the variable first `{% set seoImage="" %}` before assigning it a value! Much appreciated.